# Illuminated cloud cannot resolve symbol

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, ide, illuminatedcloud

My org has managed package.I have download my study project from git, set up connection via tools > illuminated cloud > configure project. I authorized to org with token but still cann't push code to org without console and all realted to custom code is not resolved . I pushed code to org via sfdx and then  generated offline symbol table but its the same.  How can I fix it? I tried to delete offline symbol table and generete new or regenerate, but it doesnt change anything.

UPD: I am looking into offline symbol table and class exist here, but methods still is not resolved.

Comment: Are the signatures for the methods on the class in the managed package visible in that class when you look at that class via the Setup UI on your org?

Answer (score 2):

If the stub Apex class in the offline symbol table contains the referenced method(s), my guess is that the referencing source code is not under a configured source root. Take a look at this documentation for how to configure source roots:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html

If that doesn't resolve the issue, feel free to reach out directly at support@illuminatedcloud.com and we gather additional diagnostic info.